# Print two tables/datagridview in one page using DGVPrinter

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

Im trying to print two datagridviews in one page using DGVPrinter/DGVPrinterHelper. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: paste your working code of printing each datagridview in one page.

Comment: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18042/Another-DataGridView-Printer

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.